# How are themes applied to jquery mobile plugins?

Tags: jquery-mobile

Currently I'm working on building my first plug-in for JQuery Mobile.  I've managed to make the basic code work, however I'm struggling to understand how the themeing is applied.  After spending 2 hours of googling to no avail, I'm at a bit of a loss for where to look next.

Essentially:
How do I build my plug-in to pull styles from JQM's themes?  Is there a reference of where/how the themes are applied at the mechanical level I can use?  The plugin I'm building is a somewhat customized progress bar display and I'd like the color and borders of the bar to use the theme.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery Mobile themes are based on a standard set of classes that relate to visual characteristics. For example the `.ui-btn` class should be added to buttons and the `.ui-icon` class should be added to icons to follow the jQuery Mobile theming convention. Another example is how you can add `.ui-icon-shadow` class to an element with the `.ui-icon` class and it will be given a shadow.

Here is an example jQuery Mobile button:

```
<a href="../../" data-icon="home" data-iconpos="notext" data-direction="reverse" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-up-f" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="f" title="Home">
    <span class="ui-btn-inner ui-btn-corner-all">
        <span class="ui-btn-text">Home</span>
        <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-home ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
    </span>
</a>
```

So you can either add these classes to your HTML markup manually, or you can create widgets using the functions that jQuery Mobile exposes:

```
$('<ul data-role="listview"><li>FOOBAR</li></ul>').listview();
```

*Source: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.1.0/docs/lists/lists-methods.html*

There are functions like `listview()` for all the widgets and most of them can take-in options so you can set whether the widget gets box-shadow or whatever else.

**Update**

To have your widget inherit the closest theme you can do something like this:

```
//assuming `this` is the widget element
var theme = $(this).closest('[data-theme]').attr('data-theme') || 'a';
```

Comment: Is there any mechanism to extend the theme so that if in the html a developer puts data-theme="b" that the engine will know to add a specific lettered class to the element?  
 
For example:  
I've created a tag in the plugin: <div class="widgetPluginBar">

I wish to apply the class ui-btn-a to it if theme "a" is applied.
 
Is there an extant mechanism I should be using or do I have to write a theme application function for the plugin?

Comment: That will be up to you to initialize and refresh your widget. I would do something like, `$(this).closest('[data-theme]')` to get the closest inherited theme for an element. You can use some code like that to add theme specific classes to your widget.

Comment: Just built a theme application algorithm directly into the widget itself.